# Connecting two PCs via RTP and pulseaudio and no sound

Tags: linux, audio, pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up two PCs and send audio from one to the other using RTP. I'm seeing metadata on the other PC but there's no sound. I've tried to listen RTP stream on the other PC, but it produces no output.
Configuration files and pactl output: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=2116995

Any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: can you run wireshark on each and verify that a) the sender is actually sending RTP sound data, and b) that it's actually reaching the receiver?